# I'm confusing in applying many to many relationship in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, web, frameworks

I'm making library system by using Laravel 5.1 but i'm confusing in applying the many to many relationship by Laravel between three table ( books , authors , books_authors_relationship ) if i want to make page ( author.blade.php) to display information of author and what is all books that is published by this authors and the link of this page take parameter id for author to display information of this author when click on the book author name at book page .

I have controller for book and for author , also i have model for book and for author but i don't know how i can make relation between page of book to take author id of clicked book and passing to author page ( author/1) to display information of this author through controller by using Eloquent Model !

I already made that as the following :

Book Model

```
public function author()
{
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Author');

}
```

at Author.blade.php

```
<div class="container" >
    <div class="panel panel-default">


      <h1>Welcome : {{ $author->id }}&nbsp;  </h1>

      <br>


    </div>
</div>
```

at Author Model :

```
public function books()
{
     return $this->hasMany('App\Book');

}
```

at bookController , show() fun :

```
public function show($id)
{
     $date = date('Y-m-d');
     $time = date('H:i:s');
     $author = Book::find($id);
     return   view('libraryViewsContainer.author',compact('author',$author)->withDate($date)->withTime($time);

}
```

at rout :

```
Route::resource('/author','authorsController');
```

at book.blade.php page to make request to author page through link :

```
<td>
                <?php $authors=$array_of_authors[$i]; ?>
                @foreach($authors as $author)
                <a href="/author/{{$author->id}}"><span class="label label-info">{{ $author->first_name}}</span></a>
                @endforeach
                <?php $i=$i+1; ?>
            </td>
```

what is missing in this methodology ? .All thongs it's working true only the problem in author page , I got white page when make request on author/1 page from book page

Can you help me !

Comment: Ever heard of laracasts? https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/21

Answer (score 0):

> **First of all your naming convention for schema isn't correct your**
>   **three tables should be books, authors, auther_book**

Your **`auther_book`** table should contain just two columns **`author_id`** & **`book_id`**

Then your models should be I guess

```
namespace App;

use App\Author;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Book extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function authors()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Author::class);
    }
}

namespace App;

use App\Book;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Author extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function books()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Book::class);
    }
}
```

and then your controller

```
\App\Book::with(['authors'])->get();//You may also import the class by using use App\Book
```

> **You can watch this video**
>   **[Many to Many Relations (With Tags)](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/21) &**
>   **perhaps the whole series it's very useful & free**

Comment: I edited my sharing can you see the code as above , also name of pivot table it's not problem because we can determine it at Model inside relationship if we want that